# htaccess rewrite #section to /section

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have a problem with htaccess

I'm making a website for a Youtube creator and to improve my SEO I need some htaccess rule so it likes that the users vists another page (that improves Google Listing)

My website contains sections (like `<section id="contact">`)

I'm trying it with /contact
Rewriting website.com/#contact to website.com/contact but when I try to do so , it results in 404 (The requested URL /nieuw/contact was not found on this server.)

Currently I have a file called .htaccess (root/nieuw/.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^/contact$ %{HTTP_HOST}/#contact [L]
```

I also tried it without %{HTTP_HOST}

Directory structure:

```
-root
--nieuw
---index.php with sections
--oud
--.htaccess that contains `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ nieuw/$1 [L]`
  (and some other stuff that isn't relevant for this question)
```

Can someone tell me what I do wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: I want to show /contact to the users, with the content off /index.php#contact

Comment: Anything after `#` is not for the server, it is for clients to handle that. Server just sends content of `index.php` to browser.

Comment: So, according to your explanation. It isn't possible to achieve my idea?

Comment: Not in `mod_rewrite`. You can handle it in Javascript.

Comment: What is the best way to achieve it in JavaScript?